# Angular Material Date Picker Feature

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

In angular material date picker we can set min date, max date and some other features.

```
<md-datepicker flex ng-model="birth_date" md-placeholder="Enter birthdate" md-min-date="minbirthdate"></md-datepicker>
```

But we have to choose particular month or year by scrolling and crossing all the **dates**, months and years in between. It takes lots of time to choose particular date. Is there any way to choose direct month or year?

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version,You can set `md-mode="month"` working demo below

```
 <md-input-container flex="100" layout="column">
          <div style="font-size: 10px; color: blue;" label ng-bind="::dateFields[2].label"></div>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields.selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields.required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields.locale"
                     md-mode="month"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eV2Kmt?p=preview)**